# Use PostgreSQL array_to_string in Phoenix

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have 2 `n-n` relationships between `posts` and `tags` tables. This is my query in Postgres:

```sql
SELECT t0.*, array_to_string(array_agg(t2.tag), ', ')
FROM "posts" AS t0
INNER JOIN "posts_tags" AS t1 ON (t0.id = t1.post_id)
INNER JOIN "tags" AS t2 ON (t1.tag_id = t2.id)
GROUP BY t0.id
```

I tried to use something similar in `Ecto`:

```ex
Repo.all(
  from p in Post,
    join: a in Post_Tag, on: p.id == a.post_id,
    join: t in Tag, on: a.tag_id == t.id,
    select: {p, array_to_string(array_agg(t.tag),', ')},
    limit: ^limit,
    offset: ^offset,
    group_by: p.id
)
```

But I get this error:

```
(Ecto.Query.CompileError) `array_to_string(array_agg(t.tag()), ', ')` is not a valid query expression.
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a [fragment/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) for the `array_to_string(...)` portion of your query. I have not tested it, but it should look something like:

```
fragment("array_to_string(array_agg(?), ', ')", t.tag)
```